# charAt method and strings

Tags: java, string

This line of program is suppose to test a string to make sure it is 5 characters and starts with the character "u". Right now it is only testing whether the string is 5 characters not the second part of the test?

```
String UID;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the Student's UID in the form of u####");
            UID = input.nextLine();
            if (UID.length() != 5) {
                System.out.println("INCORRECT INPUT");
            }
        } while (UID.length() != 5 && UID.charAt(0) != 'u');
        return UID;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your condition check as follows:

```
do {
    //... 
    if(UID.length() != 5 || UID.charAt(0) != 'u') {
        //incorrect input
    }
} while(UID.length() != 5 || UID.charAt(0) != 'u');
//continue until either of the conditions is true
```

And you don't need the check inside the loop itself.

IMO, it would be better to do the condition check just once

```
while(true) {
    //... 
    if(UID.length() != 5 || UID.charAt(0) != 'u') {
        //incorrect input
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also make use of the [`String.startsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify greatly:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter the Student's UID in the form of u####");
    String UID = input.nextLine();
    if (UID.length() == 5 && UID.charAt(0) == 'u') {
        return UID;
    }
    System.out.println("INCORRECT INPUT");
}
```

and even further by

```
...
if (UID.matches("u....")) {
...
```